# Creating Polygon with 50'000 vertices?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, vertices

Is there a way to automatically create a new polygon in an existing Feature Class with over 50'000 Vertices using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2?

Comment: There are some cool implementations of random polygon generation in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997099/algorithm-to-generate-random-2d-polygon). As for ArcGIS, no idea.

Comment: Can you expand more on your question why you want to create polygon features >50K vertices?

Comment: There is a Maximum amount of Vertices I can use in order to let the dataset pass as valid. If I extend the allowed amount, the check-Tools I use should give a warning. I need this polyogn to test, if the check-tool is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try doing this using 3-4 steps:

1. Create a point
2. Buffer it to create a circle
3. [Densify](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm) it using a small enough distance to create 50,000+ vertices (needs Standard or Advanced level license)
4. Append if you need to move it into another shapefile.

The above process may be best done in a shapefile because the circular buffer will be a true curve if done in a file geodatabase.